# How do I solve this logarithmic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

the equation is

$\ln(x+2)=\ln e^{\ln2} - \ln x$

How do I solve for $x$?

Comment: $e^{\ln 2} = 2$, for starters

Comment: can you explain why ?

Comment: @user293849: Think about it: What does "$\ln 2$" *mean*?

Comment: @user293849 Look up the logarithm identities $\ln a^b = b \ln a$. In your case $b=\ln 2$ and $\ln e=1$. Please have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities

Answer (score 4):

Your equation is equivalent to $$\ln (x+2)+\ln(x)=\ln2.$$
Then use logarithm identity $\ln ab=\ln a +\ln b$\$
$$\ln (x+2)x=\ln2.$$
Now take inverse of both sides
$$(x+2)x=2.$$
Now you can solve the quadratic equation and select the appropriate $x$ value.
You get $x=-1\pm\sqrt 3.$ Note that you can not take $x<0$ as $\ln x$ is not defined for negative $x$. So your answer is $x=-1+\sqrt 3$ which is approximately equal to $0.732$.